# Cannot assign values to struct members

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct, structure

I have dynamically allocated a structure array representing a series of points. However, when I try to assign values to its members, the program assigns different values than it is supposed to. What am I doing wrong?

Output of the program:

```
xy[0].x= 0 
xy[0].y= 0 
xy[1].x= 1 
xy[1].y= 1 
xy[2].x= 2 
xy[2].y= 2 
xy[3].x= 1041 
xy[3].y= 0
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n;

struct point{
  int x,y;
};
typedef struct point Point; 


void resize(Point*xy) 
{
    xy=(Point*)realloc(xy,sizeof(Point));

    for (n=0;n<4;n++)
    {
    xy[n].x=n;
    xy[n].y=n;
    }   
}


int main () 
{
   Point *xy;
   xy=(Point*)malloc(2*sizeof(Point));

   for (n=0;n<2;n++){
       xy[n].x=n;
       xy[n].y=n;
   }       

   resize(xy) ; 
   for (n = 0; n<4; n++) {
       printf("xy[%i].x= %i \n",n,xy[n].x);
       printf("xy[%i].y= %i \n",n,xy[n].y);
   }       

   free(xy);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `resize()`, you only `realloc()` enough room for one struct... and save the result to `xy` from the argument list, so if the address changes the `xy` in `main()` will still contain the old address (though since you're shrinking the array, `realloc()` will likely return the same address anyway).

Comment: You should either pass a `Point **` instead of `Point *` to `resize()`, or return `Point *` to assign back to `xy` in `main()`.

Comment: Always check the result of functions which can yield a critical error like `realloc`. And don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Answer (score 2):

> What am I doing wrong?

- The **problem** is that while you are *reallocating* the size of `xy` int `resize()` function, you are not allocating sufficient memory:

  ```
  void resize(Point*xy) {
  xy = (Point*) realloc( xy, sizeof(Point));
  ```
- here, `realloc(xy,sizeof(Point));` allocates memory for only `1` structure thus you can access only `xy[0].x` and `xy[0].y`
- but, in the for loop you access `xy[1]`, `xy[2]` and `xy[3]` ... this is

  > **accessing out of bounds** and this results in [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

and thus, you get undefined output.

---

**Solution :**

> **allocate sufficient memory using** `realloc()`

- As you've iterated the for loop `4` *( n= 0 to 3 )* times, I suppose you need to allocate memory for `4` structures
- Just multiply 4 to the second argument of `realloc()` in the `resize()` function

  ```
  xy = (Point*)realloc( xy, 4*sizeof(Point)); //multiply with 4
  ```
- here sufficient amount of memory is allocated to store `4` structures

---

**output :** *(after the change)*

```
xy[0].x= 0 
xy[0].y= 0 
xy[1].x= 1 
xy[1].y= 1 
xy[2].x= 2 
xy[2].y= 2 
xy[3].x= 3 
xy[3].y= 3
```

- *The result you get is as expected :)*

---

**Suggestions :**

Firstly,

- **Don't** *cast* the value of `malloc()` *(and* `realloc()`*)* as they return `void` type which gets automatically converted to the data-type of pointer that it's getting assigned to.
- so instead of :

  ```
  xy = (Point*)realloc(xy,4*sizeof(Point)); //same for malloc dont cast
  ```
- use

  ```
  xy= realloc(xy,4*sizeof(Point));
  ```

For further reading see this : [*click*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/5281962)

---

and then,

- **Don't** use `int main()`, instead use `int main(void)` as no arguments are being sent into `main()` function.But, in first case that is `int main()`, any number of arguments can be sent into `main()` function...

Comment: The indexing brackets dereference it for him -- `xy[0].x` will work, `xy[0]->x` will not.

Comment: @Dmitri thanks figured that out... thanks for the mention :) i've edited the answer

Comment: @PintoDoido Pleasure helping you :) ! If this has helped answering your question, you can mark it as answer for future viewers to know that this explains and solves the problem..

Comment: main can receive 0, 2 or 3 arguments. The 3 arguments variant is int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp). (just to be pedantic). I'll only ask whether this is gcc-specific or is portable.

Comment: @PaulStelian true.. But as OP is not sending any arguments into main() i thought it'd be better to suggest him on using int main(void)

Comment: @CherubimAnand I have never done this and anyway I'm more accustomed with C++ where the two declarations are equivalent. Also, C99 is compatible with K&R or has the same semantics as C++? You imply the former...

Comment: @PaulStelian In C++, there is no difference, both are same.
Both definitions work in C also, but the second definition with void is considered technically better as it clearly specifies that main can only be called without any parameter. For more see this: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-int-main-int-mainvoid/

Comment: @CherubimAnand Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @PaulStelian No problem :) and by the way no need to return 0 at the end of main()..as most of the modern compilers automatically return zero on reaching end of main. Apparently this info was shared to me by other user, so i just pass the knowledge around :)

Comment: @CherubimAnand Of course this is only implied with the main() function in C++ (in C I've seen implicit values vary and be meaningless), as a special case.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your resize function:

```
void resize(Point*xy) {
    xy=(Point*)realloc(xy,sizeof(Point));  // changes local variable

    for (n=0;n<4;n++)
    {
        xy[n].x=n;
        xy[n].y=n;
    }   
}
```

Firstly, you shrink the size of the allocation from `2*sizeof(Point)` to `sizeof(Point)`. `realloc`s second argument is the new *total* size of the allocation, not how much you want to add.

Secondly, your function only modifies the local variable `xy`, it does not return it or make the caller aware. In main:

```
   // imagine xy = 0x10000.
   resize(xy) ;  // frees 0x10000 and allocates new memory
   // xy here is still 0x10000
```

You need to either take a `Point**` pointer in resize or you need resize to return it's local xy value:

```
Point* resize(Point*xy) {
    int n;
    xy=(Point*)realloc(xy, 4*sizeof(Point));

    for (n=0;n<4;n++)
    {
        xy[n].x=n;
        xy[n].y=n;
    }   

    return xy;
}
```

or

```
void resize(Point** xyp) {
    int n;
    *xyp=(Point*)realloc(*xyp, 4*sizeof(Point));

    for (n=0;n<4;n++)
    {
        (*xyp)[n].x=n;
        (*xyp)[n].y=n;
    }   
}
```

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int x, y;
} Point;

void resize(Point** xyp) {
    int n;
    *xyp=(Point*)realloc(*xyp, 4*sizeof(Point));

    for (n=0;n<4;n++)
    {
        (*xyp)[n].x=n;
        (*xyp)[n].y=n;
    }   
}

int main () {
    int n;
    Point *xy;
    xy=(Point*)malloc(2*sizeof(Point));

    for (n=0;n<2;n++)
    {
        xy[n].x=n;
        xy[n].y=n;
    }       

   resize(&xy) ; 

   for (n = 0; n<4; n++) {
        printf("xy[%i].x= %i \n",n,xy[n].x);
        printf("xy[%i].y= %i \n",n,xy[n].y);
   }       

   free(xy);

   return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/gIntgl